# Extension 'commands_files/say' could not be loaded

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm using these 2 following codes, and the bot won't add cogs, but it works for my other bot.

My folders are the right ones because it wouldn't tell that error else.

Main code:

```py
#!/home/bist1484/virtualenv/winterlounge/3.7/bin/python3.7

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
# import subprocess
import os
import traceback
import json

import botsettings as bs

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")

try:
    for filename in os.listdir('./commands_files'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            client.load_extension(f'commands_files.{filename[:-3]}')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Say cog:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

import botsettings as bs

class Say(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    def is_staff(ctx):
        if (ctx.guild.get_role(651372813436846091) in ctx.author.roles) or ctx.author.id in bs.trustedUsers:
            return True

    # Say command
    @commands.command()
    @commands.check(is_staff)
    async def say(self, ctx, *, text):
        if ctx.channel.id not in bs.modmailChannels:
            await ctx.send(text)
            await ctx.message.delete()

            embed = discord.Embed(title="Special command used", color=0x6f6f6f)
            embed.set_author(name="ctx.author.name", icon_url="ctx.author.avatar")
            embed.add_field(name="Command used", value="{ctx.invoked_with}", inline=False)
            embed.set_footer(text=f"Jump URL: {ctx.message.jump_url}")
            await self.client.get_channel(bs.logsChannel).send(embed=embed)


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Say(client))
```

I'm getting the following error:

```sh
Extension 'commands_files/say' could not be loaded
```

Do you have any idea why that is happening?

EDIT: Here's my files structure. Note that commands_files have to be in the cgi-bin, because the start.py file is in.

[image: Files structure]

EDIT 2: I succeed to get the full traceback, here it is.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/bist1484/virtualenv/winterlounge/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 621, in load_extension lib = importlib.import_module(name)
File "/home/bist1484/virtualenv/winterlounge/3.7/lib64/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'say' The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/bist1484/winterlounge/bot.py", line 32, in client.load_extension("say")
File "/home/bist1484/virtualenv/winterlounge/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 623, in load_extension raise errors.ExtensionNotFound(name, e) from e discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionNotFound: Extension 'say' could not be loaded.
```

Comment: what does your folder structure look like?

Comment: @LuM Edit made to the question

Comment: What is your main code (the startup file)? Bot.py or start.py.

Comment: My main file is start.py, which starts bot.py

Comment: @Gugu72 Another question the main code is the main file right (start.py)?

Comment: No the main code is the main code of bot. The start.py file is not here, it just starts the bot.py (main file) file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find what was wrong with that but succeed to make this works by putting all files in the same folder as `start.py`.